# change timezone phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, timezone

How do I change timezone in phpmyadmin if between local with live different ?

This is Local

[image]

and Live

[image]

whereas in index.php I've set date_default_timezone_set (' Asia/Jakarta ');

Answer (score 1):

run this

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Jakarta';
```

in SQL tab

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 1):

@Rejoanul Alam

Bear in mind that some MySQL servers may not have the TZ tables loaded - so therefore using the name form in the SET time_zone statement may not work, in which case you will have to instead use a UTC offset value i.e.

```
SET time_zone = '+10:00';
```

The issue with this is that it doesn't automatically take into account Daylight Saving Times (whereas the named version does as the TZ - TimeZone - tables are loaded into MySQL with that info).